# pandas/seaborn - plot heatmap data distributions on a square grid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I would like to plot a spatial 2D distribution of data on a heatmap through pandas and seaborn. Let's say I have this simple `codes.csv` file:

```
Code,Value
2,4
5,6
7,1
9,2
10,1
```

Plotting a simple heatmap in seaborn is easy, just:

```
df = pd.read_csv('codes.csv',index_col='Code')
```

then

```
sns.heatmap(df)
```

returns

[image]

What I would like to do is plotting a whole 5 x 5 square grid, where the index of the dataframe represents the cell number, i.e. starting from 0, of the codes of a 5 x 5 grid like the following (top to bottom):

```
20,21,22,23,24
15,16,17,18,19
10,11,12,13,14
5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,4
```

and the resulting heatmap should map the `Code` column of the dataframe to the grid representation (so that the cells from 11 to 25 should be colored in white, as no values is there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot looks a bit strange. :-) Anyway, the key steps are first set background color to white via `sns.set(style="white")`, and then plot heapmap with `mask` parameter to remove those unwanted values.

```
# your data
# ==============================================================

df

   Code  Value
0     2      4
1     5      6
2     7      1
3     9      2
4    10      1


data_mat = df.set_index('Code').reindex(np.arange(25)).values.reshape(5,5)[::-1]
data_mat

array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  6.,  nan,   1.,  nan,   2.],
       [ nan,  nan,   4.,  nan,  nan]])

# create a mask for NaN values, these values won't be plotted
mask = np.isnan(data_mat)

mask

array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)


# plot
# ==============================================================
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="white")
f, ax = plt.subplots()
# use a diverging color to emphasize on negative and positive corr
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(12, start=2.5, as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(data_mat, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, ax=ax)
```

[image]